Preserving subplots when assembling them into a parent plot using Plotly make_subplots and add_trace
Here is sample code from the plotly website to make error bars:
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    name='Control',
    x=['Trial 1', 'Trial 2', 'Trial 3'], y=[3, 6, 4],
    error_y=dict(type='data', array=[1, 0.5, 1.5])
))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    name='Experimental',
    x=['Trial 1', 'Trial 2', 'Trial 3'], y=[4, 7, 3],
    error_y=dict(type='data', array=[0.5, 1, 2])
))
fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
fig2 = fig
fig.show()

Here is the same code except that multiple instances of the code are being enclosed into a plot:
# Create a grid of subplots
i_s_num_subs = 8
obj_s_fig_mv_all = make_subplots(rows=(i_s_num_subs-1) // 2 + 1, cols=2)
# Add a bar plot to each subplot
for i_s_plot in range(i_s_num_subs):
    i_s_row = i_s_plot // 2 + 1
    i_s_col = i_s_plot % 2 + 1
    i_s_num_phases = 4
    obj_s_fig_mv_tc = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=i_s_num_phases)
    i_s_sub_col = 0
    for i_s_sub_col in range(i_s_num_phases):
        obj_s_fig_mv_tc.add_trace(
            go.Bar(
                name='Control',
                x=['Trial 1', 'Trial 2', 'Trial 3'], y=[3, 6, 4],
                error_y=dict(type='data', array=[1, 0.5, 1.5])
            ),
        row=1,
        col=i_s_sub_col+1
    )
    obj_s_fig_mv_tc.update_layout(barmode='group')
    obj_s_fig_mv_all.add_trace(obj_s_fig_mv_tc.data[0], row=i_s_row, col=i_s_col)
obj_s_fig_mv_all.show()

You will see that the assembled plot is very different from the components. I think it happens because individual traces from the subplots are being added to the enclosing plot. Is there a way to preserve the look and feel of the subplots and use the enclosing plot just to place them in a grid? Something like faceting with plotly express?

Perhaps I lack understanding. I don't understand your goal very well. Can you be more specific? If you are wondering if there is a way to make the second graph easier, the facet function in express is easy to use. See the reference for more details.

I am trying to implement faceting on plotly graphobjects. Faceting is available only in the plotly express layer.
